# How can I update my page details ? in c# with mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to do add and update issues on the same form. 
[Here is the "SAYFA EKLE" that form. It means "Add New Page"in english.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATeRS.png)

```
    public ActionResult Insert(Pages pages, string parent, string optactive) 

   {
    Pages pages_ = new Pages();

        pages_.pageName = pages.pageName;
        pages_.pageURL = pages.pageURL;
        if (optactive == "on") pages_.isActive = true;
        else pages_.isActive = false;
        pages_.orderNumber = pages.orderNumber;

        int parid = 0;
        try
        {
            parid = Convert.ToInt32(parent);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        pages_.parentId = parid;

        if (parid == 0) pages_.levelNumber = 0;
        else
        {
            var partemp = db.Pages.Where(o => o.id == 
  parid).FirstOrDefault();
            if (partemp.levelNumber == 0) pages_.levelNumber = 1;
            else pages_.levelNumber = 2;
        }

  db.Pages.Add(pages_);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect(Url.Content("~/Page/"));
    }
```

Here is my Adding Action. It works well.

```
    [HttpGet]
    private ActionResult EditPost(string pageId)
    {

        var id = Convert.ToInt32(pageId);  //Edit Action
        var tmppage = db.Pages.Where(o => o.id == id).First();
        ViewBag.tmppage = tmppage;
        ViewBag.pages = returnPages();

        return View("Index");
    }
```

Thats also my EditPost action. I can retrieve the data from databas for using same form.

```
<div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">SAYFA EKLE</div>
        <div class="panel-body">

            <form action="~/Page/Insert" method="post">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-
 hover">
<tr>
    <td>Sayfa Adı</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="pageName" 
placeholder="Sayfa ismini giriniz" value="@if (ViewBag.tmppage != null) { 
@ViewBag.tmppage.pageName } " required/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Sayfa Adresi</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="pageURL" 
placeholder="Sayfa adresini giriniz"   required/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Aktif/Pasif</td>
    <td>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optactive" value="on" required>Aktif
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optactive" value="off" required>Pasif
        </label>

    </tr>
```

Thats my View also. SO How can I update my records ? Also I'm using entity frame work code first from database.  I am really new at coding. I'll glad you if you help me to done my Internship project.

Answer (score -1):

First of all. You completely missed the MVC principle here. Try to read more bout it.

If you are using a form and a model in your view you need [HttpPost] before your action.

```
[HttpPost]   // this 
public ActionResult Insert (Pages pages) 
{
        Pages pages_ = new Pages();
        ....
```

Your get method can accept int values, why are you using string?

```
[HttpGet]
private ActionResult EditPost(int? pageId)
{
    if (pageId == null) 
        ...do somrthing;

    ViewBag.tmppage = db.Pages.FirstOrDefault(o => o.id == pageId); 
    ViewBag.pages = returnPages();

    return View("Index");
}
```

And your view HAS to have a Model which pages in your case. and FORM tag should look differently.

```
   @model Pages // your first line in the view
   ...
   <form asp-action="Insert" asp-controller="Pages">
       <input asp-for="pageName" class="" />
       <input asp-for="isActive" class="" />
       .... and etc.
```

This is just partial answer. Just spend a little bit more time reading the documentation. However, I do recommend to you to watch this videos, they are short but very-very good for you.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYMOUCVo86jFPCV6_u2m8P2NE2LSijvLN

Comment: If this is MVC 5, why are you using `asp-action` and `asp-controller`?

Comment: Because MVC5 has tag-helpers. And you can use them. Believe me, you gonna love them.

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/2039284.aspx?What+is+the+advantage+of+using+Tag+Helpers+in+ASP+Net+MVC+5

Comment: The forum post you linked to is not about MVC 5. The OP was mistaken. MVC 5 does not have Tag Helpers.

Comment: Tag Helpers are available in MVC 5. Google it. But it is up to you if you need a solution. Any ways there different ways to solve the problem. I just offered one of them. Doesn't have to be the easiest and the best.

Comment: I did Google it, just to verify. And it turns out, Tag Helpers are *not in MVC 5*. You *prove it* if you think they are. It seems you don't know the difference between MVC 5, MVC 6, ASP.NET 5, MVC Core 1.0, and ASP.NET Core. I am not the one asking the question, I am not seeking a solution. However, you have provided a solution that will not work for the platform that the asker has tagged their question as. Therefore, your answer is incorrect. Please correct your answer to be applicable to the relevant framework.

Comment: @mason no comments. I guess we are using different Google. However, instead of writing this comment you could spend your time on helping the person, who asked the question.

Comment: You have provided an answer that is not applicable to what was asked. This site is community moderated. That's just how it works. *MVC 5 does not have Tag Helpers*, your answer is not applicable.

Comment: Tag Helpers were introduced originally with what was known as MVC 6, which ran on the ASP.NET 5 platform. Those have been renamed to ASP.NET Core MVC and ASP.NET Core respectively. That is probably the source of your confusion. It's understandable that you're confused, because Microsoft has had a confusing naming scheme. But it does not excuse you from rejecting this information once it's been pointed out to you, and from continuing to argue that you're correct and to leave incorrect information out there.

Comment: @mason I ask you again to use all your emotions and energy to help with the question, not to try to prove something to me. No need in that. Don't waste your time on me.

Comment: Having correct answers goes a long ways towards helping with the question.

Comment: @JackMov of course I added model in my view then i used [HttpPost]. I didnt send all of my view  codes. I dont think i totally misunderstand MVC principle.asp-actions are unnecessary.I am using string because most of my variables pagename,pageurl etc are string and when i used int the action cant return pageId. The Error say pageId is null. Thanks your helping. But I would like to learn how can i edit my values.